# ¿Por qué no se estan insertando todos los valores que agrego a mi base de datos desde mi app android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Estoy haciendo una *app* que recibe datos de un dispositivo médico (Electrocardiograma) por **bluetooth**. Cuando recibo los datos de este sensor, los cargo en listas y los envío a una base de datos. Sin embargo, cuando intento visualizarlos no se están guardando todos los datos en la base.

Se que los datos están en las listas por que verifico con un `System.out.print...` el contenido de estas.
¿Alguien tiene idea de por que pasa esto?

Esta es la clase donde hago las conversiones necesarias y cargo los datos del dispositivo a las listas:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;


public class DataParse implements Runnable
{
    private final String         TAG                 = getClass().getName();
    private final static int     BUFFER_SIZE         = 1024;
    private final int[]   PACKAGE_HEAD        = new int[]{0x55,0xaa};
    private final int     PKG_ECG_WAVE        = 0x01;
    private final int     PKG_ECG_PARAM       = 0x02;
    private final int     PKG_NIBP            = 0x03;
    private final int     PKG_SPO2            = 0x04;
    private final int     PKG_TEMP            = 0x05;
    private final int     PKG_SW_VER          = 0xfc;
    private final int     PKG_HW_VER          = 0xfd;
    private final int     PKG_SPO2_WAVE       = 0xfe;

    private int skipCounter = 0;
    private Handler mHandler;


    private byte[] recvData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    private int    emptyIndex = 0;
    private int    parseIndex = 0;

    public DataParse(Handler handler)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mHandler = handler;
    }

    public void Add(byte[] buf, int bufSize)
    {
        boolean pkgStart = false;
        int pkgIndex = 0;
        int pkgLength = 0;
        byte[] pkgData = null;


        if(bufSize+emptyIndex <= BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, recvData, emptyIndex, bufSize);
            //System.ar
            //System.out.println("recvData prueba: "+recvData);
            emptyIndex = (emptyIndex+bufSize) % BUFFER_SIZE;
        }
        else if( (bufSize+emptyIndex > BUFFER_SIZE) && (bufSize+emptyIndex < 2*BUFFER_SIZE))
        {
            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, recvData, emptyIndex, BUFFER_SIZE-emptyIndex);
            int temp = emptyIndex;
            emptyIndex = 0;
            System.arraycopy(buf, BUFFER_SIZE-temp, recvData, emptyIndex, bufSize-(BUFFER_SIZE-temp));
            emptyIndex = bufSize-(BUFFER_SIZE-temp);
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Receive too much data.");
            return;
        }

        if(bufSize < 5) return;

        int i = parseIndex;
        while (i != emptyIndex) {

            if ((recvData[i]&0xff) == PACKAGE_HEAD[0]) {//recvData[i]&0xff para enmascarar datos, devulve solo el primer caracter de recvData
                int j = (i + 1)%BUFFER_SIZE;
                if (j != emptyIndex && (recvData[j]&0xff) == PACKAGE_HEAD[1]) {
                    int k = (j+1)%BUFFER_SIZE;
                    if(k != emptyIndex)
                    {
                        pkgLength = recvData[k]&0xff;
                        pkgData = new byte[pkgLength+2];
                        pkgStart = true;
                        pkgIndex = 0;
                        parseIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (pkgStart && pkgLength > 0) {
                pkgData[pkgIndex] = recvData[i];
                pkgIndex++;

                if ((pkgLength != 0) && (pkgIndex == pkgLength + 2)) {
                    if(CheckSum(pkgData)){
                        ParsePackage(pkgData);
                    }
                    pkgStart = false;
                    parseIndex = (i + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
                }
            }
            i = (i + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }


    private void ParsePackage(final byte[] pkgData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int pkgType = pkgData[3]&0xff;

        switch (pkgType) {//tipo de paquete que llega

            case PKG_ECG_WAVE:
                skipCounter++;

                if(skipCounter == 1)
                {

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            MainActivity.mECGWaveDraw.add(pkgData[4]&0xff);//Aqui es donde se mandan los datos para hacer la Grafica en la pantalla principal DEL APP
                                                                            //pkgData[4]&0xff es un valor entero
                        }
                    }).start();

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Globals.lstSendECGGraphData.add(Integer.toString(pkgData[4]&0xff));//Aqui es donde agrego los datos a las listas para enviarlos a la base de datos
                        }
                    }).start();

                    ServiceManager.onSendData();//Metodo para enviar los datos a la BD
                    skipCounter = 0;
                }
                break;
            case PKG_SPO2_WAVE:

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        MainActivity.mSpO2WaveDraw.add(pkgData[4]&0xff);
                    }
                }).start();

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Globals.lstSendSPOGraphValueData.add(Integer.toString(pkgData[4]&0xff));
                        System.out.println("Datos SPO2 Grafico: "+Integer.toString(pkgData[4]&0xff));
                    }
                }).start();
                ServiceManager.onSendData();


                break;
            case PKG_ECG_PARAM:
                mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MESSAGE_ECG_PARAMS, 0xff&pkgData[6], 0xff&pkgData[5]).sendToTarget();
                break;
            case PKG_NIBP:
                mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MESSAGE_NIBP_PARAMS, 0xff&pkgData[6], 0xff&pkgData[8]).sendToTarget();

                break;
            case PKG_SPO2:
                mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MESSAGE_SPO2_PARAM, 0xff&pkgData[5], 0xff&pkgData[6]).sendToTarget();
                System.out.print("obtainMessage: "+mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MESSAGE_SPO2_PARAM, 0xff&pkgData[5], 0xff&pkgData[6]));
                System.out.println("Hexadecimal: "+pkgType);
                System.out.println("DatoHexadecimal: "+pkgData);
                break;
            case PKG_TEMP:
                mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MESSAGE_TEMP_PARAMS, 0xff&pkgData[5], 0xff&pkgData[6]).sendToTarget();
                break;
            case PKG_SW_VER:

                break;
            case PKG_HW_VER:

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    private boolean CheckSum(byte[] packageData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i < packageData.length-1; i++)
        {
            sum+=(packageData[i]&0xff);
        }

        if(((~sum)&0xff) == (packageData[packageData.length-1]&0xff))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase para enviar los datos a la base de datos en el servidor:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

public class ServiceManager
{

    public static void onLoginUser(String user,String pw,final Login activity)
    {
        String url = Globals.baseUrl + "login.php"
                +"?user=" + user
                +"&pw=" + pw;

        HttpUtil.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
        {
            public void onFailure(Throwable paramThrowable) {
                String s = "fail";
                //activity.mDialogLogin.dismiss();
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                String s = "finish";
            }

            public void onSuccess(String paramString)
            {  //that is return when success..
                System.out.println("Entrando al onSuccess");
                try
                {
                    JSONObject localJSONObject1 = new JSONObject(paramString);
                    if (localJSONObject1.has("response"))
                    {
                        String response = localJSONObject1.getString("response");
                        if (response.equals("200"))
                        {
                            JSONArray jsArray = localJSONObject1.getJSONArray("users");
                            JSONObject model = jsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            UserModel mModel = new UserModel();
                            mModel.mName = model.getString("user");
                            mModel.mId = model.getString("id");

                            int state = model.getInt("state");
                            if (state == 1)//era 0
                            {
                                Globals.mAccount = mModel;
                                activity.iniciaApp();
                            }
                        }
                        //activity.mDialogLogin.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    activity.errorIniciarApp();
                    activity.mDialogLogin.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public static void onSendData()
    {
        String graphECG="";
        String graphOX = "";
        String valueSp = "";
        String valuePr = "";
        String valueResp = "";
        String valueHr = "";
        String valueTemp = "";
        String valueHighPressure = "";
        String valueLowPressure =  "";
        String valueAirFlow = "";
        String valueSPOGraphValue = "";
        String valueSPOValue1 = "";
        String valueSPOValue2 = "";
        String valueMov = "";
        String valueGal1 = "";
        String valueGal2 = "";
        String valueGal3 = "";
        String valueECG = "";
        String valueECGGraph = "";
        String valueECG2 = "";
        String valueECG3 = "";
        String valueEMG = "";
        String valueTempArd = "";
        String valueLote = "";
        String valueTipo = "";
        String valuePruebasDato1 = "";
        String valuePruebasDato2 = "";




        //Asignacion de los datos de las listas a las nuevas cadenas creadas arriba
        if (Globals.lstSendData.size() > 0)
            graphECG = Globals.lstSendData.get(0); //Obtiene lo que tienen la lista (ECG) en la clase Globals.java
        if (Globals.lstSendData1.size() > 0)
            graphOX = Globals.lstSendData1.get(0);//Obtiene lo que tienen la lista (OXIMETER) en la clase Globals.java
        if (Globals.lstSendSpData.size() > 0)
            valueSp = Globals.lstSendSpData.get(0);//Obtiene lo que tienen la lista (SpO2) en la clase Globals.java
        if (Globals.lstSendPrData.size() > 0)
            valuePr = Globals.lstSendPrData.get(0);//Obtiene lo que tienen la lista (Pr) en la clase Globals.java
        if (Globals.lstSendResData.size() > 0)
            valueResp = Globals.lstSendResData.get(0);//Obtiene lo que tienen la lista (ResData) en la clase Globals.java
        if (Globals.lstSendHrData.size() > 0)
            valueHr = Globals.lstSendHrData.get(0);//Obtiene lo que tienen la lista (HrData) en la clase Globals.java
        if (Globals.lstSendTempData.size() > 0)
            valueTemp = Globals.lstSendTempData.get(0);//Obtiene lo que tienen la lista (Temperature) en la clase Globals.java
        if (Globals.lstSendHighData.size() > 0)
            valueHighPressure = Globals.lstSendHighData.get(0);//Obtiene lo que tienen la lista (HighPressure) en la clase Globals.java
        if (Globals.lstSendLowData.size() > 0)
            valueLowPressure = Globals.lstSendLowData.get(0);//Obtiene lo que tienen la lista (LowPressure) en la clase Globals.java
        if(Globals.lstSendAirFlow.size()>0)
            valueAirFlow = Globals.lstSendAirFlow.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendSPOGraphValueData.size()>0)
            valueSPOGraphValue = Globals.lstSendSPOGraphValueData.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendSPOValue1Data.size()>0)
            valueSPOValue1 = Globals.lstSendSPOValue1Data.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendSPOValue2Data.size()>0)
            valueSPOValue2 = Globals.lstSendSPOValue2Data.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendMovData.size()>0)
            valueMov = Globals.lstSendMovData.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendGal1Data.size()>0)
            valueGal1 = Globals.lstSendGal1Data.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendGal2Data.size()>0)
            valueGal2 = Globals.lstSendGal2Data.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendGal3Data.size()>0)
            valueGal3 = Globals.lstSendGal3Data.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendECGGraphData.size()>0)
            valueECGGraph = Globals.lstSendECGGraphData.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendECGData.size()>0)
            valueECG = Globals.lstSendECGData.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendECGData2.size()>0)
            valueECG2 = Globals.lstSendECGData2.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendECGData3.size()>0)
            valueECG3 = Globals.lstSendECGData3.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendEMGData.size()>0)
            valueEMG = Globals.lstSendEMGData.get(0);

        if(Globals.lstSendTempARDData.size()>0)
            valueTempArd = Globals.lstSendTempARDData.get(0);


        if(Globals.lstSendDatoLote.size()>0)
            valueLote = Globals.lstSendDatoLote.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendDatoTipo.size()>0)
            valueTipo = Globals.lstSendDatoTipo.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendPruebasDato1.size()>0)
            valuePruebasDato1 = Globals.lstSendPruebasDato1.get(0);
        if(Globals.lstSendPruebasDato2.size()>0)
            valuePruebasDato2 = Globals.lstSendPruebasDato2.get(0);

        final String v_ecg = graphECG;
        final String v_ox = graphOX;
        final String v_sp = valueSp;
        final String v_pr = valuePr;
        final String v_resp = valueResp;
        final String v_hr = valueHr;
        final String v_temp = valueTemp;
        final String v_high = valueHighPressure;
        final String v_low = valueLowPressure;
        final String v_air = valueAirFlow;
        final String v_spoGraph = valueSPOGraphValue;
        final String v_spo1 = valueSPOValue1;
        final String v_spo2 = valueSPOValue2;
        final String v_mov = valueMov;
        final String v_gal1 = valueGal1;
        final String v_gal2 = valueGal2;
        final String v_gal3 = valueGal3;
        final String v_ECGGraphArduino = valueECGGraph;
        final String v_ECGarduino = valueECG;
        final String v_ECGarduino2 = valueECG2;
        final String v_ECGarduino3 = valueECG3;
        final String v_EMG = valueEMG;
        final String v_TempArd = valueTempArd;

        final String v_lote = valueLote;
        final String v_tipo = valueTipo;
        final String v_pruebasDato1 = valuePruebasDato1;
        final String v_pruebasDato2 = valuePruebasDato2;



        //Envio de los datos al servidor donde se almacenaran los datos en la BD
        String url = Globals.baseUrl + "receiveData.php"
                +"?ecg=" + graphECG
                +"&ox=" + graphOX
                +"&sp=" + valueSp
                +"&pr=" + valuePr
                +"&resp=" + valueResp
                +"&hr=" + valueHr
                +"&temp=" + valueTemp
                +"&high=" + valueHighPressure
                +"&low=" + valueLowPressure
                +"&air=" + valueAirFlow
                +"&SPOGraphValue=" + valueSPOGraphValue
                +"&SPOValue1=" + valueSPOValue1
                +"&SPOValue2=" + valueSPOValue2
                +"&MovValue="+valueMov
                +"&GalValue1="+valueGal1
                +"&GalValue2="+valueGal2
                +"&GalValue3="+valueGal3
                +"&EcgGraphValue="+valueECGGraph
                +"&EcgValue="+valueECG
                +"&EcgValue2="+valueECG2
                +"&EcgValue3="+valueECG3
                +"&EmgValue="+valueEMG
                +"&TempValue="+valueTempArd
                +"&LoteValue="+valueLote
                +"&TipoValue="+valueTipo
                +"&Dato1Value="+valuePruebasDato1
                +"&Dato2Value="+valuePruebasDato2
                +"&uid=" + Globals.mAccount.mId;
        HttpUtil.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
        {
            public void onFailure(Throwable paramThrowable) {
                String s = "fail";
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                String s = "finish";
            }
//

            public void onSuccess(String paramString) {  //that is return when success..
                try {
                    JSONObject localJSONObject1 = new JSONObject(paramString);
                    if (localJSONObject1.has("response")) {
                        String response = localJSONObject1.getString("response");
                        if (response.equals("200"))
                        {
                            try {

                                if (!v_ecg.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendData.remove(0);
                                if (!v_ox.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendData1.remove(0);
                                if (!v_sp.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendSpData.remove(0);
                                if (!v_pr.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendPrData.remove(0);
                                if (!v_resp.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendResData.remove(0);
                                if (!v_hr.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendHrData.remove(0);
                                if (!v_temp.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendTempData.remove(0);
                                if (!v_high.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendHighData.remove(0);
                                if (!v_low.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendLowData.remove(0);
                                if(!v_air.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendAirFlow.remove(0);

                                if(!v_spoGraph.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendSPOGraphValueData.remove(0);
                                if(!v_spo1.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendSPOValue1Data.remove(0);
                                if(!v_spo2.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendSPOValue2Data.remove(0);
                                if(!v_mov.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendMovData.remove(0);
                                if(!v_gal1.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendGal1Data.remove(0);
                                if(!v_gal2.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendGal2Data.remove(0);
                                if(!v_gal3.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendGal3Data.remove(0);
                                if(!v_ECGGraphArduino.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendECGGraphData.remove(0);
                                if(!v_ECGarduino.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendECGData.remove(0);
                                if(!v_ECGarduino2.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendECGData2.remove(0);
                                if(!v_ECGarduino3.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendECGData3.remove(0);
                                if(!v_EMG.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendEMGData.remove(0);
                                if(!v_TempArd.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendTempARDData.remove(0);

                                if(!v_tipo.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendDatoTipo.remove(0);
                                if(!v_lote.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendDatoLote.remove(0);
                                if(!v_pruebasDato1.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendPruebasDato1.remove(0);
                                if(!v_pruebasDato2.equals(""))
                                    Globals.lstSendPruebasDato2.remove(0);


                            }catch(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){}
                        }


                        if ((Globals.lstSendData.size() > 0) || (Globals.lstSendData1.size() > 0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendSpData.size() > 0) || (Globals.lstSendPrData.size() > 0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendResData.size() > 0) || (Globals.lstSendHrData.size() > 0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendTempData.size() > 0) || (Globals.lstSendHighData.size() > 0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendLowData.size() > 0) || (Globals.lstSendAirFlow.size()>0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendSPOValue1Data.size() > 0) || (Globals.lstSendSPOValue2Data.size()>0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendMovData.size()>0) || (Globals.lstSendGal1Data.size()>0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendGal3Data.size()>0) || (Globals.lstSendGal3Data.size()>0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendECGData.size()>0) || (Globals.lstSendEMGData.size()>0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendECGGraphData.size()>0) || (Globals.lstSendSPOGraphValueData.size()>0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendTempARDData.size()>0) || (Globals.lstSendECGData2.size()>0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendECGData3.size()>0) || (Globals.lstSendDatoLote.size()>0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendDatoTipo.size()>0) || (Globals.lstSendPruebasDato1.size()>0)
                                || (Globals.lstSendPruebasDato2.size()>0)
                                )
                        {
                            onSendData();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Globals.isActivity = false;
                        }

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        });
    }
}
```

En verdad espero me puedan ayudar, ya llevo algo de tiempo y no encuentro solución, de antemano gracias.
Los datos se reciben a 1 ms, podria tener algo que ver eso con que no este insertando correctamente?

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo, espero te sirva para comprender mejor mi situacion.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, podría ser porque declaras las variables con la palabra reservada **final**?

Creo que no te hace falta, además podría ser la causa del problema. Las declaraciones que usan la palabra reservada final:

**Final**: indica que una variable es de tipo constante: no admitirá cambios después de su declaración y asignación de valor. final determina que un atributo no puede ser sobreescrito o redefinido. O sea: no funcionará como una variable “tradicional”, sino como una constante. Toda constante declarada con final ha de ser inicializada en el mismo momento de declararla. final también se usa como palabra clave en otro contexto: una clase final (final) es aquella que no puede tener clases que la hereden. Lo veremos más adelante cuando hablemos sobre herencia.

Además primero estás eliminando información, te recomiendo que siempre que tengas que usar `remove()` o un método precido lo hagas siempre al final, cuando ya has trabajado ya que podría ser que perdieras la referencia.

Comment: Buen dia, las declaro finales por que así como dices son variables que no necesitan cambiar, son constantes, en mi caso solo sirven para clasificar los datos que recibo por bluetooth.´
Pienso que el problema esta a la hora de cargar los datos en las listas, no se si es la forma correcta

Comment: No estoy eliminando primero información,  primero se carga a las listas los datos dentro de la clase DataParse, despues se manda a llamar el metodo onSendData() de la clase ServiceManager en la cual se checa si la lista tiene dato, lo toma  y lo asigna a una variable para enviarla via URL